# How to send HTML emails with images using python3 and email library?

Tags: python, html-email

I want to create script to automatically send "Happy birthday" emails to list of users. I took this function from email lib documentation [examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html):

```
def send_email(name):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(f"""
    Dear colleagues!

    Today is birthday of {name}. 
    """)
    balloons = make_msgid()
    msg.add_alternative("""\
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <img src="cid:{balloons}" />
        <h3>Dear colleagues!</h3>
        <p>Today is <b>birthday</b> of {name}!</p>
        <p>-- Colleagues.</p>
      </body>
    </html>
    """.format(name=fixed_name, balloons=balloons[1:-1]), subtype='html')

    with open("bday_balloons.png", 'rb') as img:
        #msg.add_related(img.read(), 'image', 'png', cid=balloons)
        msg.add_alternative(img.read(), 'image', 'png', cid=balloons)

    msg['From'] = Address("Notification", "info", "rtdprk.ru")
    msg['To'] = receiver_email
    msg['Subject'] = "Birthday of {}".format(fixed_name)

    with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server) as s:
        s.send_message(msg)
```

But picture doesn't load in mail client (tested on outlook 2019 and thunderbird).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it may need function to create `multipart`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are embedding the image using Content-ID (CID), which has limited email support (https://www.caniemail.com/features/image-base64/). Can you use the HTML img tag i.e. `<img src="https://www.image.com/host-somewhere-on-internet" />`?

See https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/ for more information.

Comment: Gmail and thunderbird blocks direct links to images, so i wont consider that way. Thanks for link on sendgrid article, it is gave me better understanding of embedded images.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is wrong ("Gmail and thunderbird blocks direct links to images"). Using the `<img>` tag is standard practice everywhere. Everywhere bar none.